# Concurrent unprotected operations on a Swift Array might cause which issues?

Tags: swift, concurrency

It's clean that unsynced / unlocked / unmutexed operations on a Swift data structure such as an Array could lead to memory related issues. Yet it's unclear to which issues exactly, and more importantly why. Issues such as value overridden, memory corruption and co. are unexplained.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be wise and welcomed to understand all the issues that might arise from attempting unguarded access in a multi threaded system.

Several issues that I (presume) are:

## Item overridden

2 threads attempt to append to an array. Should they start at the same Core tick they might end up overriding each others write operations.

## Memory corruption

Double free attempt might occur if 2 threads both initiate a shrink / grow event and then both go to free the old memory pointer location.

## Half value read (*not sure)

If write operations such as `a[x] = reference/value type` are themselves not atomic then it might be that a thread will start writing the address of `a[x]` while another thread will read a[x] half address.